# How to replace a specific text from the query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query:

```
select SeqNo, Name, Qty, Price 
from vendor 
where seqNo = 1;
```

outputs like below:

```
SeqNo   Name    Qty  Price
1       ABC     10   11
1       -do-    11   12
1       ditto   13   14
```

The output above shows the vendor name as ABC in first row which is correct. Later on as users entered for the same vendor name `"ABC"` as either `'-do-'` / `'ditto'`. Now in my final query output I want to replace `-do-` and `ditto` with `ABC` (as in above example) so my final output should look like:

```
SeqNo   Name    Qty  Price
1       ABC     10   11
1       ABC     11   12
1       ABC     13   14
```

Comment: only -do- and ditto? can u modify your question with more sample rows..

Comment: What rdbms? Sql Server, Oracle or?

Comment: @Prakash..in the result do you need to show `XYZ` row?

Comment: Which platform ? each db/language has it's string replacing functions or options (replace, case, decode.....)

Comment: I am using a reporting tool in which I  have to enter a SQL query backend though being MS SQL

Comment: How do you chose "first row", since they have same SeqNo?

Comment: It like the actual name is excluding '-do-' and 'ditto' which in my case above is value 'ABC'

Comment: But if there are both ABC and DEF for same SeqNo?

Comment: Yes I believe then I need to have a criteria or a new column to state in actual which vendor name they are referring to - so if any row contains do or ditto then another column name like for example row number (representing which record was entered next) such that I now know this row do or ditto is for previous row in which the actual vendor name was entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is working in sql server for you sample data..not sure how your other rows are look like

```
select SeqNo,
       case when Name in ('-do-','ditto') then 
        (select Name from test where Name not in('-do-','ditto')
        and SeqNo = 1)
        else Name
        end as Name
from table
where SeqNo = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. It works and solves my issue for the above issue

Comment: Thanks my query is always for a specific SeqNo so it always be specific. Your query helped me - however just for confirmation I believe that in case if there are multiple names apart from some dos & dittos then it is completely not possible to find or use the name in concern - please confirm. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Prakash yup thats what all users are saying.. if multiple name other than dos and ditto present for a particular seqno this wont work..you need to find a criteria for finding using which name you should do the replacement

Comment: @Prakash that table only has these three columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78990/discussion-between-sachu-and-prakash).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REPLACE` function

```
SELECT SeqNo, REPLACE(REPLACE(Name,'ditto','ABC'),'-do-','ABC'), Qty, Price
FROM vendor
WHERE seqNo = 1;
```

Comment: No I am not sure if Name  will be ABC - it would be as stored in table

Comment: @Prakash What would it be stored as?

Comment: Anything - ABC could just be a value - it can be any name

Comment: @Prakash So, what do you want the value to be replaced with? Or with what value from what table?

Comment: @Prakash using what criteria you are selecting the name to be replaced

Comment: In rows which has name as '-do-' or 'ditto'. It has to be replaced with a name. The issue our side is that some people have entered vendor name once as like 'ABC' and later on for same transaction they have entered  '-do-' or 'ditto' representing the same vendor which in this case is ABC by example

Comment: @Prakash what is the table and field that will be used to populate name when it is '-do-' or 'ditto'.?

Comment: @Prakash in the above there is row having `XYZ'`as name how to identify -do- or ditto should replace with `ABC` or `XYZ`

Comment: @Prakash Do you have an identity column on your table?

Comment: I am not sure of identity column please let me know how to find the same - also I have removed rows having 'XYZ' - so now if I have the name only be there in one row how can I replace it in place of '-do-' or 'ditto'

Comment: @Prakash If you dont know the name of the column how the hell are we meant to?

Comment: @Prakash Do you have an ID column or a unique value column in that table?

Comment: @Prakash like Matt & Radu telling you should need a primary column or you should need to know what data is inside..else its not possible

Comment: I agree with you all - I need to have a PK in the table else it is not possible at all

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`:

```
select SeqNo,
       case when Name in ('-do-','ditto') then 'ABC' else Name end as name,
       Qty,
       Price 
from vendor 
where seqNo = 1;
```

Comment: it is not always 'ABC' see the discussion in the other answer

Comment: I am so sorry if I am misleading by my question - its not like I want do & dittios to be replaced with ABC - its the name in actual that is listed. The scenario is that - users are entering do & dittios from second record once they have entered the correct name in first one

Comment: Prakash, can't you edit your question and describe how to find ABC or whatever value you want instead of '-do-' and 'ditto'?

Comment: I am sorry if my question is misleading but I have changed accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the other answers, if your requirement includes only the sample data you posted, =) this will do:

```
 SELECT SeqNo, 'ABC' Name, Qty, Price
   FROM vendor
  WHERE seqNo = 1;
```

Comment: Since you have improved your question, you can ignore my answer.